# Node.JS (Express) - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to redirect the user to a page after a method POST.

```
req.flash('failed_registration', message);
res.redirect(303, '/register');
```

This is how '/register' looks like:

```
// Registration
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register', {flash: req.flash('failed_registration'), recaptcha: process.env.RECAPTCHA_WEB, form_data: req.session.form_data});
})
```

Why am I getting "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"?
What is the correct way to redirect and use flash messages?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you already return a response elsewhere.

Comment: maybe after the `res.redirect` you are returning anothe res?

Comment: Can you please share the full code? It seems like you're already sending a response before the redirect.